# On demand count inventory scan efficiently in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to display total inventory from adding incoming inventory and subtracting out going inventory, on demand from PostgreSQL database. I have not figured out how to set up triggers and/or SQL.

We are scanning at two RFID portals, in and out. Scans are posting to a SQL database table (trans). This table gets up to 300,000 records each year before we reset. Looking to display total inventory at any time. I am thinking I need set up a trigger to subtotal items and save in another table before session is posted. This would make the data much smaller.

Then I would need to total all the sessions on demand or use another trigger to total sessions. Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this?

Session cols:

```
id            = record id
session_id    = Session id
loc_id        = gate 1 = out, 2 = in
inv_item      = inventory item id, one per line
created_at    = date
```

Comment: 300,000 records is a very small amount of data for a database so I wouldn't bother with triggers unless you are absolutely sure you need it. Focus on getting the queries correct and learn how to index efficiently.

Comment: Alternate solution provided by: "[SQL conditional addition or subtraction](//stackoverflow.com/q/1429769/90527)".

Answer (score 1):

300000 rows is really quite a small number (I typically don't start performance testing with less than a million).

With an index on `inv_item` the following query should be fast enough (assuming decent hardware):

```
select count(*) filter (where loc_id = 2) - count(*) filter (where loc_id = 1)  as inventory
from the_table
where inv_item = 1234;
```

The first `count` expression counts all "in" rows and the second count counts all "out" rows, subtracting them from the first. The difference between all "in" rows and all "out" rows is the current inventory.

If you need it for items for a given session, you can use:

Or if you need it for multiple inventory items:

```
select inv_item, 
       count(*) filter (where loc_id = 2) - count(*) filter (where loc_id = 1) as inventory
from the_table
group by inv_item
where session_id = 9876;
```

And index on `inv_item` will speed up the first query, an index on `(session_id, inv_item)` will speed up the second query.